# When do I use '#include <string>' at the start of a C++ program?

Tags: c++, string

I am confused about the use of `#include <string>` at the start of a program. For example, in the code below, I don't use `#include <string>` but the function will still print out the string "Johnny's favorite number is" when it is run.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void printVariable(int number){
    cout << "Johnny's favorite number is" << number << endl
}
```

However, in this code below, it does contain `#include <string>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Var{
    public:
        void setName(string x){
            name = x;
        }

        string getName(){
           return name;
        }
   private:
       string name;
};

int main(){
    Var Classy;
    Classy.setName("Johnny Bravo");
    cout << Classy.getName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Do I only use `#include <string>` if a variable represents a string?

Comment: use it when you need something from that header file.

Comment: `"Johnny's favorite number is"` is *not* a `std::string`.  It is of type `const char *`.  A C-style string, we say.

Comment: `#include <something>` *guarantees* that you *may use* certain facilities (often types and functions). If you omit it, and use those facilities anyway, it may build or not; it might even build but behave strangely.

Comment: @5gon12eder It is of the type *array of 28 `const char`*.

Comment: You need to `#include` headers to declare *identifiers* you use. In your first example, you never refer to any identifiers from `<string>`, thus you don't need that header. In your second example, on the other hand, you refer to the type `std::string` at several lines; therefore, you need the proper header to be included. If you didn't include `<string>` there, the compiler would stumble at identifier `string` and complain because it would have no declaration.

Comment: Strictly speaking a "string" is a general concept that can be implemented in many different ways. At the language level C++ has limited support for character strings that are, by convention, null terminated. That's supplemented by the library `<cstring>` that makes handling that kind of string implementation easier. The `<string>` library actually provides a different implementation of strings. You only need to `#include <string>` if you actually use the facilities it provides. String "literals", which is what you are using, are built into the language.

Comment: @Galik I absolutely agree and as a result even if one compiles the above program without <string> header, it would compile fine as you aren't using any implementation/facilities provided by the <string> header.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Do I only use `#include <string>` if a variable represents a string?

Yes.

Use `#include <string>` when you use a variable that has type `std::string`.

The code `"text here"`, contrary to intuition, is not a `std::string`; it is a *string literal*, and a C-style string, and a `const char[10]` convertible to `const char*`. Welcome to C++ with its legacy oddities.

Answer (score 4):

Your question arises from the fact that you know that something like `"aabcd"` is a *string* literal. So, its type should be `string`. Well, that's not quite true.

C++ has a lot of features from C. Including data types. So, that is a pointer to char (`char*`), not a `string`(an instance of the `string` class). You can create an instance of the `string` class from a `char*` (including a string literal) by passing it as argument to the constructor of `string`. But it is not a string, it's just some misleading terminology.

A similar case is calling things vectors when they are arrays.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the type `std::string` in your code then you should include the `<string>` header. There are also a few other types and functions in that header, but `std::string` is the most commonly used one.

However, you do not need to include this header just to use string literals, which are built into the core language.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case, library "string" is not needed. The object "cout" is supported by library "iostream", thus you have:

```
#include <iostream>
```

For the second case, you do explicitly use "string", thus library "string" is required:

```
#include <string>
```